# Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The column name CustomerId is specified more than once

Tags: sql-server, .net-core, entity-framework-core

In my business model a Contact can optionally have one Customer but a Customer can have many Contacts.

When I have the following relationship set in `OnModelCreating`:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
            .HasOne<Customer>()
            .WithMany(x => x.People)
            .HasPrincipalKey(c => c.CustomerId)
            .HasForeignKey(p => p.CustomerId);
```

How do I set up the relationship correctly to avoid the error?

The following unit test fails on `SaveChanges`:

```
[TestMethod]
public void T011_AddContactShouldwork()
{
    var db = DataHelpers.MakeDbContext();
    var Customer = db.Customers.FirstOrDefault();
    var person = new Contact();
    Customer.People.Add(person);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

If I remove the relationship then the unit test passes.

The business objects are defined with

```
public class Customer
{
    public Customer()
    {
        People = new List<Contact>()
    }

    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Contact> People { get; set; }
}

Public Contact()
{
    public int ContactId { get; set; }
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public virtual Customer { get; set; }  // this is optional
}
```

I am using .net5 with

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.1.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="5.0.14" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.14" />
```

I ran a trace to get the SQL and it is

```
exec sp_executesql N'SET NOCOUNT ON;
INSERT INTO [Contact] ([Comments], [CustomerID], [CustomerId], [Email], [Extension], [FirstName], [LastName], [MiddleName], [Mobile], [ShipToAddress], [ShipToCity], [ShipToContactName], [ShipToCustomer], [ShipToPostCode], [ShipToState], [Suffix], [SupplierID], [Title])
VALUES (@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4, @p5, @p6, @p7, @p8, @p9, @p10, @p11, @p12, @p13, @p14, @p15, @p16, @p17);
SELECT [ContactID]
FROM [Contact]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT = 1 AND [ContactID] = scope_identity();

',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000),@p1 int,@p2 int,@p3 nvarchar(4000),@p4 nvarchar(4000),@p5 nvarchar(4000),@p6 nvarchar(4000),@p7 nvarchar(4000),@p8 nvarchar(4000),@p9 nvarchar(4000),@p10 nvarchar(4000),@p11 nvarchar(4000),@p12 nvarchar(4000),@p13 nvarchar(4000),@p14 nvarchar(4000),@p15 nvarchar(4000),@p16 int,@p17 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=NULL,@p1=453,@p2=NULL,@p3=NULL,@p4=NULL,@p5=NULL,@p6=NULL,@p7=NULL,@p8=NULL,@p9=NULL,@p10=NULL,@p11=NULL,@p12=NULL,@p13=NULL,@p14=NULL,@p15=NULL,@p16=NULL,@p17=NULL
```

I tried making the Person's CustomerId required and the error changes to

```
 Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. 
 See the inner exception for details. ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 
 Invalid column name 'CustomerId1'.

  Stack Trace: 
SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean isAsync, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, String method)
SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
<7 more frames...>
BatchExecutor.Execute(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection)
RelationalDatabase.SaveChanges(IList`1 entries)
StateManager.SaveChanges(IList`1 entriesToSave)
StateManager.SaveChanges(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
DbContext.SaveChanges()
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
HasOne<Customer>
```

I needed

```
HasOne(x=>x.Customer)
```

So the relation is

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ContactExt>().HasOne(x=>x.Customer).WithMany(x => x.People).HasPrincipalKey(c => c.CustomerId).HasForeignKey(p => p.CustomerID);
```